# How can 3rd party app "A" let novice iOS device users open an MP3 file downloaded by 3rd party app "B"?

Tags: ios

My goal is to make an iOS app that includes the ability for the user to open MP3 files that were downloaded (by the same user) within a different 3rd party app, similar to the functionality of a ringtone maker that relies on opening files that the user has already downloaded. If I understand correctly, this is easy to do if the "other" app is Apple's native iPod music player app, via the "iPod Library Access" interface. Hopefully I have at least that part right.

But what if the "other" app is a non-Apple 3rd party app, through which the user downloaded the MP3 file that we now want that user to be able to open within our app? From a high level (I'm not asking for code), how is this done? And has your analysis changed based on what was announced for iOS 7?

Comment: Mmmmmmm that's where I love Android intents ... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to be possible, the third-party app in question must expose some mechanism for doing this. They might implement hooks through the sharing charm, or they might expose a "documents" repository from which other applications can read (optionally, with granted permissions from the user to do so). For example, the AirShare application can read your Dropbox files. This is because Dropbox has exposed the files as a documents repository and the user has granted permission for AirShare to access Dropbox. If the third-party app doesn't implement these hooks, there is no way to access the documents from another application.

**Edit:**

To access the music files in the user's iTunes library, I'll refer you to the iPod Library Access Programming Guide at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/iPodLibraryAccess_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: Thank you for the instructive answer. Any chance that you can confirm my premise that my desired functionality is built in if the user downloads the MP3 via Apple's native iPod music player app?

Comment: Yes, you can! Check out my edit above and refer to the iPod Library Access Programming Guide :)